# undefined index error when update button is pressed?

Tags: php, html

i have here a select option and it work fine if i change the value of the option but when i try not to change anything and i pressed on the update button it gives me an error of `undefined error`. but if i change the value of a option it successfully updated. I really do not know why its giving me this error..

**my code**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';


$Reason_for_Deduction = isset($_GET['Summary_of_Reason']) ?      $_GET['Reason_for_Deduction'] : '';

if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    $Reason_for_Deduction = $_POST['Summary_of_Reason'];

    if($LTID->update($ID,$Summary_of_Reason))
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!');</script>";
    }
}
    if(isset($_GET['ID']))
    {
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    extract($LTID->getID($ID)); 
}
?>
```

**update.php**

```
<select name="Summary_of_Reason" id="yearapproved" class=form-control required/>
       <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" <?php echo $Summary_of_Reason; ?>><?php echo $Summary_of_Reason; ?></option>
       <option value="18% SLOPE ABOVE AND UNDEVELOPED">18% Slope and Undeveloped</option>
       <option value="FIVE (5) HAS. AND BELOW">5 Has. and Below</option>
       <option value="CANCELLED TITLE">Cancelled Title</option>
       <option value="CANNOT BE LOCATED ON THE GROUND">Cannot Be Located on the Ground</option>
       <option value="COMMUNAL FOREST">Communal Forest</option>
       <option value="DISTRIBUTED BEFORE CARPER">Distributed Before Carper</option>
       <option value="DUPLICATE LH">Duplicate Lh</option>
       <option value="ERODED; SILTED/ROCKY NOT SUITABLE TO AGRICULTURAL">Eroded;Silted/Rockt not suitable to Agricultural</option>
       <option value="HANDOG TITULO">Handog Titulo</option>
       <option value="HOMESTEAD PATENT">Homestead Patent</option>
       <option value="IRRIGATION CANAL">Irrigation Canal</option>
       <option value="LANDS FOR PUBLIC USE">Lands for Public Use</option>
       <option value="LH IS W/N SWAMPY, MANGROVE AREA">Lh is w/n Swampy, Mangrove Area</option>
       <option value="LO DIED PRIOR TO CARP">LO Died Prior to CARP</option>
       <option value="PASTURE LAND">Pasture Land</option>
       <option value="ROAD LOT">Road Lot</option>
       <option value="TIMBERLAND">Timberland</option>
       <option value="USED FOR INFRASTRUCTURE">Used for Infrastructure</option>
       <option value="W/N PROCLAIMED AREA">w/n Proclaimed Area</option>
       <option value="W/N DANGER ZONE">w/n Danger Zone</option>
       <option value="W/N UNCLASSIFIED PUBLIC FOREST">w/n Unclassified Public Forest</option>
       <option value="W/N WATERSHED AREA">w/n Watershed Area</option>
       <option value="WORKABLE">Workable</option>
</select>
```

**class.php**

```
public function update($ID,$Summary_of_Reason)
{
try
{
$stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE rlbet SET Summary_of_Reason = :Summary_of_Reason WHERE ID = :ID");

$stmt->bindparam(":Summary_of_Reason",$Summary_of_Reason);

$stmt->bindparam(":ID",$ID);
$stmt->execute();

  return true;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
  return false;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the full error?  Check the line number.  It does seem odd you are checking both `$_GET` and `$_POST` for Reason_for_Deduction.

Comment: At least one option should be selected.

Comment: keep this line in starting of your page, error_reporting(E_ERROR);ini_set("display_errors",1);

Comment: Use selected='selected' `<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" <?php echo $Summary_of_Reason; ?>>`

Comment: @TheBigbyteNumber i tried what you suggested and now there's no error why is that?

Comment: @RuchishParikh i already tried that but it gives me errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled" <?php echo $Summary_of_Reason; ?>><?php echo $Summary_of_Reason; ?></option>
```

to:

```
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $Summary_of_Reason; ?>"><?php echo $Summary_of_Reason; ?></option>
```

You are echoing the value of `$Summary_of_Reason inside` the option tag and not as its value and the main problem is `selected = "true"` needs to be changed to `selected="selected"`.

Comment: woooah! it worked! can you explain me why my code is not working?

Comment: While technically this is true, the option's value will not be affected and this will not address the error in the question.  Value is an optional attribute for options.

Comment: @Trojan Because the first option didn't have a value. You were missing the value attribute in the first option and you were echoing the value of $Summary_of_Reason directly into the option element and not as its value. so when submitting, the value of `$Reason_for_Deduction = $_POST['Summary_of_Reason'];` was null. Hope this helps

Comment: So much bad advice in this thread.  @OsamaSayed, option's value is optional.  A null value does not result in an undefined error.

Comment: @Devon what do you think happens when the value of `$Summary_of_Reason` is missing in this line? `$LTID->update($ID,$Summary_of_Reason)` ?? it tries to update a null doesn't it?

Comment: @Devon what do you mean by that?

Comment: @OsamaSayed Where in your answer do you address `$Summary_of_Reason` of the **my code** section?

Comment: @Devon I mean you said "A null value does not result in an undefined error." It does if you are trying to use `$Summary_of_Reason` in this line `$LTID->update($ID,$Summary_of_Reason)` while its value is null!

Comment: @Devon in my answer I just added `value="<?php echo $Summary_of_Reason; ?>` to the option and changed `selected="selected"`.

Comment: I guess the error happened because of the two things together, first you wrote `selected = "true"` while it should be `selected = "selected"` and second the first option didn't have a value. so `$_POST['Summary_of_Reason'];` always was `null`. Clear now?

Comment: @OsamaSayed and that won't change anything because the same value is already set between the option tags.   `<option>summary</option>` is the same as `<option value='summary'>summary</option>`

Comment: @Devon Why do we have the attribute value then? if `<option>summary</option>` is the same as `<option value='summary'>summary</option>`?? of course value is the value of the option selected while the text between <option> tags is just the text displayed in this option!

Comment: @OsamaSayed, go try it.  This is basic HTML.  Option's value is optional.  If it's excluded, the value will be the same as the display.  Also, this has nothing to do with the PHP undefined error because a null value is not the same as an undefined variable.

Comment: @OsamaSayed https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option#HTML_Attributes "If there isn't, the value of an option element is the textContent of the element. "

Comment: when i try to press the update button without changing tanything the option it is successfully saved the problem is that the current record is not now displaying

Comment: @Devon Yes you are right. Thanks for sharing this info here. Then definitely the problem was selected="true" not being selected="selected". Agree?

Comment: On the HTML side, yes, but there is still an issue with the PHP code (undefined error) but with the given example not using the right variable names and not including the full error / line number, we can't really determine that problem.

Comment: @Trojan can you share with us the code of `$LTID->update` ?

Comment: guys can you just help me with this? i'm asking a question here

Comment: I noticed in your function you wrote this:

`public function update($ID,$Summary_of_Reason,)` there is a ',' in the end of the function parameters list. Change it to `public function update($ID,$Summary_of_Reason)`

Comment: same problem occur..when i press the update button without changing the current value of the option it update successfully but it submits a null value in the database that's why its not displaying my my option..help please?

Comment: @Trojan Okay let's echo out the value of `$Summary_of_Reason` inside the update function. You can add this line: 

`echo "Value of Summary_of_Reason is $Summary_of_Reason";` and share the echo result please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115177/discussion-between-osama-sayed-and-trojan).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to remove the / from the end of

Also your select box name is "Summary_of_Reason" then why you are using $_GET["Reason_for_Deduction"] in action page, You should use $_GET["Summary_of_Reason"]. "Reason_for_Deduction" is not available in form, this is the reason it gives you undefined index error.

Comment: i'm sorry my mistake..just a typo error..i already updated my question

Comment: why is this downvoted? he's right..i just have a mistake posting make question but now i updated it

Comment: @Trojan, because this answer isn't technically correct.  There is an isset call on the $_GET variable, so there would be no error resulting from that variable in your code.